# Proving Graphs Properties (common neighbors)

Tags: graph-theory

I'm struggling with two different-but similar questions. I'm pretty new with the subject so will really appreciate explanation on how to approach these kind of question

1. Prove that in every 10 vertices graph with 28 edges there are 2 vertices with two different neighbors.
2. Prove that in any graph G with $|V|=n$ and $d(v)=\sqrt(n)$ $\forall v\in\ V$
   there is a triangle or 2 vertices with two different neighbors.

Comment: Are there any precisions for 1 ?  Does it have to be connected ?  Because you can take $K_8$, the complete graph on 8 vertices, then add 2 isolated vertices (vertices with no edges incident to them).   This graph has 10 vertices, and no pair of vertices have different neighbors.

Comment: But the proof should be for any 10 vertices Graph with 28 edges, not only the complete graph

Comment: And I wrote the question as it's written in the book (translation from Hebrew)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't provide a proof - it's a counter-example to show that NOT every 10 vertices graphs have this property.  My guess is that is it assumed that the graph is connected.

Comment: okay, assuming it's connected- any suggestions?

Comment: I don't wanna bother you, but is "having two different neighbors" formally defined ?  Because from my understanding of it, 1. is false and 2. is (almost) trivial, so that's strange. My interpretation : say I have a graph on 4 vertices $a,b,c,d$ with $E(G) = \{ab, bc, cd, da\}$.  Then $a$ and $d$ are two vertices with two different neighbors (because $a$ has $b$, and $d$ has $c$).

Comment: That's my interpretation either. but how do I prove that in a graph with 10 vertices and 28 edges- there are always 2 vertices like the ones mentioned above?

Comment: And 3 might be trivial to you :) would appreciate an explanation :)

Comment: Edited answer to include the solution for the second problem. Note that a better (and stronger) version of the second problem reads: "Prove that in any graph $G$ with $|V|=n^2$ and minimum degree at least $n$ there is a triangle or 2 vertices with at least two common neighbours".

Answer (score 3):

The title talks about "common neighbours", but the question itself is about "different neighbours".
This answer will convince you that "common neighbours" are meant.

We need a few lemma's. I'll just state them, they are easy to prove, let me know if you have trouble.
$G$ is our graph, $n$ is the vertex count, $e$ the edge count.

Lemma 1:
The average "sum of degrees" over pairs of different vertices is twice
the average degree (in formula: $\frac{\sum_{v\ne w}(d(v)+d(w)}{n}=\frac{4e}{n}$).

Lemma 2:
If we have vertices $v$ and $w$ with $d(v)+d(w)\geq n+2$ then $v$ and $w$ have at least two common neighbours.

Lemma 3:
If we have vertices $v$ and $w$ with $d(v)+d(w)\geq n$ and $G$ is triangle-free then
$v$ and $w$ have at least two common neighbours.

The first problem:
Lemma 1 tells us that the average "sum of degrees" is $\frac{4e}{n}>11$.
The pigeonhole principle now gives us a pair $v,w, v\ne w$ with $d(v)+d(w)\geq 12=n+2$,
so lemma 2 tells us that $v$ and $w$ have two common neighbours.

Note that the proof fails for $e=27$, which is strong evidence that "common neighbours"
is the proper choice to make.

The second problem is easier (or at least more common knowledge).
Note that "no two vertices with 2 common neighbours" is equivalent to "no $C_4$".
So we just need to show that a graph with girth 5 (no triangle $C_3$ and no $C_4$)
and minimum degree degree at least $n$ has more than $n^2$ vertices and this is a standard result:

let $v$ be an arbitrary vertex. $v$ has at least $n$ neighbours $w_1,\ldots,w_n$.
Each of this neighbours has itself has at least $n-1$ neighbours different from $v$. $w_i$ cannot
be a neighbour of $w_j$ (or we would have triangle $vw_iw_j$) and $w_i$ can $w_j$
cannot have a common neighbour $z$ (or we would have $C_4$ $vw_izw_j$).
So $G$ has at least $1+n+n(n-1)=n^2+1$ vertices.

Comment: Very nice !  Though it's still instructive to try to answer 1) as stated in the question !

Comment: @manuellafond:
The question as posed is rather unclear.
The most obvious interpretation leads to a question that is trivial and pointless.
The answer would be:
there are at least 2 vertices of degree at least 2, so there are two vertices with two different neighbours.